# How to send layout from one activity to another activity in android?

Tags: android

I have a dynamically built Layout in Main Activity. Now I want to send this complete Layout to another Activity. How can I send ?

Comment: have you constructed a viewgroup ? is that what you mean by creating a layout ?

Comment: Your question is not clear, you don't "send" layouts between activities. Perhaps you're looking for fragments: a fragment has a lifecycle which is  independent. Though it can be attached to an activity or multiple activities.

Answer (score 1):

@Milad gh:
Also can make a layout.xml for temp and use it as interface:

```
my_root = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.my_root);
LinearLayout A = new LinearLayout(this); // is your layout than you want to create
A.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
A.addView(view1);
A.addView(view2);
A.addView(view3);
my_root.addView(A)
```

Then you can use my_root in other activity or make public static "A" layout and use it to another activity su as that Milad gh said

Answer (score 0):

you can define your layout public static, and get it in other classes or activities, 
for example :

```
public class Main extends Activity {
public static LinearLayout my_root;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    my_root = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.my_root);
    LinearLayout A = new LinearLayout(this);
    A.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    A.addView(view1);
    A.addView(view2);
    A.addView(view3);
    my_root.addView(A);}
}
```

and in another activity:

```
LinearLayout L2 = new LinearLayout(this);
L2.addView(Main.my_root);
```

Comment: And you got memory leak at the end.  You should remove reference to my_root in onDestroy at least.

Comment: It's not working for me. Is there any way through serialization